# iOS CoreLocation Geocoder Crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I am having a crash that is 100% reproducible, but I am wondering if it is a result of improper use of CoreLocation, or if I can safely blame it on the library.  The issue is in CoreLocation, and can be reproduced in XCode7.2 inside of a Swift Playground.

What the code attempts to do is use reverse geolocation to map a zip code to a city name.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import AddressBookUI
import XCPlayground

let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
var addressDict: [String : String] = [:]

// Change to a valid zipcode to see it not crash
addressDict[kABPersonAddressZIPKey as String] = "1010"

geocoder.geocodeAddressDictionary(addressDict) { (returnedPlacemarks, error) -> Void in
  if returnedPlacemarks != nil && returnedPlacemarks!.count > 0 && error == nil {
    if let city: String = returnedPlacemarks![0].addressDictionary![kABPersonAddressCityKey as String] as? String {
      print(city)
    }
  } else {
    if error != nil {
      print("Failed to match city")
    }
  }
}

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

The issue is that entering 1010 as a zip code causes it to crash.  If you attempt to use a valid zip code, it will behave properly.

In an actual project, it crashes within CoreFoundation, with the following output

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
```

Here's the first three lines of the stack trace

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bee2e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dc22deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bdc6404 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
```

Does anyone see any issue with my code, or should I file a bug report with Apple?  Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't crash in that case, I'd file a bug report. I'd expect that the error in the should be set, but not that it would crash. Make sure you send this playground along with your bug report along with what you expect should happen in this case.